# div.find_element_by_xpath.text value not coming

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the reviews content of https://www.tiaa.org/public/offer/products/life-insurance using below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(html_page)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="bv-hero-ALL-LIFE-INSURANCE"]/span[2]/span[2]""").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
reviews_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('bv-content-item bv-content-top-review bv-content-review')
author = ''
summary = ''
product_family = ''
gender = ''
occupation = ''
reason = ''

driver.switch_to_frame(0)
for div in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol'):
    author = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h3')
    print(author.text)
    summary = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p')
    print (summary.text)
    product_family = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/a')
    print(product_family.text)
    gender = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[3]/ul/li[5]/span[2]')
    print(gender.text)
    occupation = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[3]/ul/li[4]/span[2]')
    print(occupation.text)
    reason = div.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[3]/ul/li[2]/span[2]')
    print(reason.text)
```

I tried .getText() also..but no luck.. any pointers please...

Comment: Can you share xml of the page containing control , which text you are trying to get.

Comment: that is probably because there is n o element as "BVRRContainer" on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `getText()` & `text` is not working is because the element you are trying to access are hidden (I guess by CSS) and `getText()` only fetches the visible innerText. There are 2 elements on the DOM (for each user) which contains information about the author name. Of these 2, one is hidden (which you are accessing) & one is visible (which you should be using).

The xpath for author names which should work is:

`//*[@id="BVRRContainer"]/div/div/div/div/ol/li[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3`